# The map generated by the googleway package is not updated after pressing the other tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, googleway

The code below generates two maps, one being generated by the `googleway` package and the other by the `leaflet` package. See in the image that a region is selected in `selectInput` and automatically two maps are generated. If I change my `selectInput` with another option, the map automatically updates the new locations. This is working fine. The problem is when I go to the other `tabPanel`, that is "Distance between locations", and I try to choose another region to showe the map again, only the map generated in the `leaflet`updates, the map generated by `googleway` does not, this is strange. Any help on this problem?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

set_key("API KEY")

df1<-structure(list(ETEs = c("Location1", "Location2", 
                             "Location3", "Location4", "Location5", "Location6", 
                             "Location7", "Location8"), Latitude = c(-22.8851078223344, 
                                                                     -22.8315940282463, -22.9269302273894, -22.7168354545552, -22.4049856273179, 
                                                                     -23.6335639883851, -23.8650940097111, -22.2258061474773), 
                    Longitude = c(-48.4939312250395,-48.4298167144681, -48.4594335076124, -48.5783308965308, 
                                  -48.1690878117765,-49.3218749756598, -48.0149391697704, -48.7246763738941), 
                    Region = c("Centro-Oeste Paulista", "Centro-Oeste Paulista", "Centro-Oeste Paulista", "Centro-Oeste Paulista", "Nordeste Paulista",
                               "Nordeste Paulista", "Nordeste Paulista", "Nordeste Paulista")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")


function.test<-function(df1,selected_regions){

  df_filtered <- df1 %>% 
    filter(Region %in% selected_regions)
  
  plot1<-google_map() %>%
    add_markers(data = df_filtered, lat = "Latitude", lon = "Longitude", info_window = df_filtered$ETEs)%>%
    clear_traffic() %>%
    clear_polylines() %>%
    clear_markers() %>%
    add_traffic() 
  
  plot2<- leaflet() %>%
    addMarkers(data = df_filtered, lat = ~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude) 
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Plot2" = plot2
  ))
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(), 
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 
                                 selectizeInput("hours",
                                                label = h5("Choose the region:"), choices = NULL,
                                                multiple = TRUE,
                                                options = list(maxItems = 1))),
                               
                               
                               mainPanel(
                                 tabsetPanel(      
                                   tabPanel("Map",google_mapOutput(outputId = "mapWarsaw1",width = "80%", height = "400"),leafletOutput(outputId = "mapWarsaw2", width = "80%", height = "400")),
                                   tabPanel("Distance between locations"))
                               )
                             )
                    )
  ))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  df1_reactive <- reactive(function.test(df1, input$hours))
  
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "hours",
                         choices = unique(df1$Region)
    )
  })
  
  output$mapWarsaw1 <- renderGoogle_map({
    req(input$hours)
    df1_reactive()[[1]]
  })
  
  output$mapWarsaw2 <- renderLeaflet({
    req(input$hours)
    df1_reactive()[[2]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Map OK**
[image]

**Map after press `tabPanel Distance between locations` and try to generate the maps again**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 df1_reactive <- reactive(function.test(df1, input$hours))
```

I'd start by swapping this to an eventReactive.

```
df1_reactive <- eventReactive(input$hours, {
                              function.test(df1, input$hours)
                })
```

But I think your problem is that by switching tabs you are suspending the execution. See here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/outputoptions

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce without an API key but try this:

```
# Disable suspend for output$myplot
outputOptions(output, "mapWarsaw1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, it worked! I did `outputOptions(output, "mapWarsaw1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`